# ¿Cómo puedo pintar una tabla en Markdown?

Tags: soporte, formato

Tenía entendido que este sitio usa Markdown para pintar prácticamente todo, pero tal vez estoy algo oxidado. ¿Cómo puedo agregar una tabla en este sitio usando markdown?

Esto es lo que intenté:

````
```
|Clave|Cantidad|Signo |id_transaccion|
| --- | ------ | ---- | ------------ |
| 001 |  10    |   -1 |     D001     |
| 002 |  30    |   -1 |     D002     |
| 003 |  5     |    1 |     D003     |
| 001 |  3     |    1 |     D004     |
```
````

Desafortunadamente se ve así:

> [image: tabla visualizándose bien gacho :C]

Answer (score 9):

Desde [finales de 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/209901) ya es posible hacer tablas normales usando `|` para separar las columnas y `-` para marcar el título.

Así, un código como:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

se ve así:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Se pueden hacer bastantes cosillas con ellas, como por ejemplo alinearlas:

```
| izq | centro | derecha |
|:--- |:-----:| ------:|
| A   | B     | C      |
```

Que se ve así:

| izq | centro | derecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |

---

Anteriormente tenían que hacerse en bloques de código. Por ejemplo, [a 8 de enero de 2019, ya funciona usar ```` ``` ```` para marcar el código](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/209901). De este modo, tu código:

````
```
|Clave|Cantidad|Signo |id_transaccion|
| --- | ------ | ---- | ------------ |
| 001 |  10    |   -1 |     D001     |
| 002 |  30    |   -1 |     D002     |
| 003 |  5     |    1 |     D003     |
| 001 |  3     |    1 |     D004     |
```
````

Ahora se muestra correctamente:

```
|Clave|Cantidad|Signo |id_transaccion|
| --- | ------ | ---- | ------------ |
| 001 |  10    |   -1 |     D001     |
| 002 |  30    |   -1 |     D002     |
| 003 |  5     |    1 |     D003     |
| 001 |  3     |    1 |     D004     |
```

---

Anteriormente (esto es, antes del 8/1/2019) en lugar de los

`````
````
`````

Que no los admitía el markdown de Stack Overflow, una serie de líneas solo se marcaban como código usando cuatro espacios delante de cada línea:

```
    |Clave|Cantidad|Signo |id_transaccion|
    | --- | ------ | ---- | ------------ |
    | 001 |  10    |   -1 |     D001     |
    | 002 |  30    |   -1 |     D002     |
    | 003 |  5     |    1 |     D003     |
    | 001 |  3     |    1 |     D004     |
```

Answer (score 6):

La sintaxis que utilizas es la correcta en Github, sin embargo aquí todavía no hay soporte para tablas markdown como lo dice [ésta pregunta en stackoverflow en inglés](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) y tampoco ésta declarada en la [documentación oficial de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

Igual podrías hacer uso de herramientas externas, como [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables), donde copiando y pegando los datos que pones de ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
| Clave | Cantidad | Signo | id_transaccion |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
| 001   | 10       | -1    | D001           |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
| 002   | 30       | -1    | D002           |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
| 003   | 5        | 1     | D003           |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
| 001   | 3        | 1     | D004           |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
```

O, en su caso, dentro de la página dar:

- File
- Paste Table (pegar el contenido de tu tabla en el área de texto)

  - Load
- Generate

Simplemente, sería otra forma que suelo usar cuando se requiere formatear tablas.